# Identifying DeviceIoControl argument

Tags: windows, debuggers, winapi

I am reversing an application that uses the serial interface (COM1 port) and am using API Monitor to trace through the API calls.

I found a reference to `CreateFileA("\\.\Commsb96", GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL)`. I believe this is opening the serial port.

Shortly afterwards, the code runs `DeviceIoControl`, with the `dwIoControlCode` (second parameter) set to `0x0022002b`.

API Monitor identified that as IOCTL_INTERNAL_USB_RECORD_FAILURE. Given that this is not a USB device, I suspect this is a mislabeling. If so, how do I identify what `0x0022002b` is?

And if not, what the heck is IOCTL_INTERNAL_USB_RECORD_FAILURE. The calling DLL is VcomSB96.dll.

Thank you!

Comment: These are probably **not** COM devices. COM device descriptor names are in the format of "\\.\COM1". where the digit 1 represents the COM device id. Is it possible that the application loads it's own driver?

Comment: According to [Microsoft](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/24653.decoding-io-control-codes-ioctl-fsctl-and-deviceiocodes-with-table-of-known-values.aspx?Sort=MostUseful&PageIndex=1), `0x0022002b` is also `IOCTL_BTHHFP_STREAM_OPEN` which hints at a bluetooth device. Are you sure that's a real com port, or rather a bluetooth adapter that emulates RS232 over bluetooth? I found this by googling for 0x0022002b; in many cases googling for this kind of specific magic number yields something useful.

Answer (score 1):

As Nirlzr said, this was not a **COM1** device. It was a virtual device, which functioned as an intermediary to the actual COM1 interface.
I debugged the .sys file, which was just using IOCTL_INTERNAL_USB_RECORD_FAILURE, but was merely using that IOCTL command.

Answer (score 1):

The meaning of any one Device I/O Control code is subject to some convention. Microsoft defines the code in bit fields, the most notable of which is the high word as a device type. Microsoft defines many I/O control codes for many types of device. If a driver is executing to handle that type of device, it should expect to receive those corresponding I/O control codes and to interpret them as Microsoft defines. These I/O control codes are in this sense well-defined such that if you or a diagnostics tool see one, identifying it by a known symbolic value is sound.

However, drivers can create device objects that have nothing to do with hardware. Such devices won't be the target for any device I/O control to help with managing any type of device that the system knows or cares about, and so the driver can make up whatever I/O control codes it wants. This is a long established mechanism by which drivers communicate with a co-operating application.

Conventionally, I/O control codes that are invented for this purpose tend to have 0x0022, i.e., FILE_DEVICE_UNKNOWN, as the device type. The practical consequence for you in your reverse engineering is that the same device I/O control code that has 0x0022 as the high word can mean completely unrelated things to different devices, even if implemented in the same driver.

Now, Microsoft does muddy the water a little by using FILE_DEVICE_UNKNOWN for I/O control codes that can be sent to drivers for physical devices. But unless you or your diagnostics tool know that you're looking at a driver that's in place to receive those I/O control codes, any symbol that the tool resolves a 0x0022XXXX number to is very likely a fantasy that you do better to ignore.